# Custom UIViewController not receiving orientation change notifications on device rotation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

So, I have a custom UIWindow, a custom UIViewController, and a custom UIImageView.

```
private class CoachingWindow : UIWindow
{
    public CoachingWindow(...)
    {
        RootViewController = new CoachingOverlayViewController(...);
    }

    private class CoachingOverlayViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public CoachingOverlayViewController(...)
        {
            View = new CoachingOverlayView(...);
        }

        public override void DidRotate (UIInterfaceOrientation fromInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            ...
        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
        {
            return true;
        }

        private class CoachingOverlayView : UIImageView
        {
            public CoachingOverlayView(...)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The window, view controller, and view all display properly when first called: the custom UIWindow appears as an overlay over the rest of the existing UIWindows, the view controller is properly assigned as the RootViewController, the view is assigned to the View property of the view controller. So, it all renders correctly.

However, the overridden DidRotate() and ShouldAutorotate() methods never get get called when I physically rotate the device or simulator.

I'm thinking it may have something do with the fact that I'm using a custom UIWindow. Perhaps the window isn;t receiving notifications of orientation change from iOS? Or does iOS send these notifications directly to view controllers? Maybe I have to somehow make the view controller subscribe to these events because it's a custom view controller???

I'm using MonoTouch and iOS 6.

Any suggestions would be great. I'm beating my head against the wall here.

Comment: have you tried -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in iOS 6 you can use

```
    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had override ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation) instead of ShouldAutorotate(). But this is actually deprecated in iOS6. Still have to figure out how to do it the iOS6 way, but this will do for now.

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: Are you supporting iOS6 **only** devices ? If so then you can stop using deprecated methods whenever you wish (or until Apple *removes* them, keep in mind there are still methods available that were deprecated in iOS 2.0). OTOH if you support people using iOS 5.x (or earlier) then continue using the existing (it's still there and works in iOS6) methods. In some cases the replacement method can offer some advantages and you might want to support both (old and new) code paths inside the same app (for the best experience for each iOS version) but that's not very common.

Comment: I'm required to support iOS 5 for this release.

Comment: Then *try* to avoid API deprecated in iOS 4.3 (and earlier) release(s) as it will make future maintenance of your code easier. Also do **not** use API introduced in iOS 6.0, even if it deprecates API in 5.0 (unless you have fallback code for iOS5 and are ready to test both code paths).